# Starting wxFrame using ctypes in Python

Tags: python, c++, wxwidgets, ctypes

I have a DLL file (scisuit_plot_d.dll) and there is a plot function namely *c_plot*. The DLL has dependencies on a few other DLLs. The signature of *c_plot*:

```
extern "C" DLLPLOT PyObject * c_plot(PyObject * y, PyObject * x);
```

The implementation (stripping details) is:

```
auto frmPlot = new wxFrame(nullptr, wxID_ANY, "test frame");
frmPlot->Show(true);
```

To be able to call this function from Python I am using *ctypes* library as follows:

```
import ctypes as ct

path = parent_path(__file__) + "scisuit_plotter_d"
plt = ct.PyDLL(path)

plt.c_plot.argtypes = [ct.py_object, ct.py_object]
plt.c_plot.restype=ct.py_object

hwnd = plt.c_plot(y, x)
print(hwnd)
```

The DLL main part of scisuit_plotter_d is:

```
HANDLE ThreadId;

class wxDLLApp : public wxApp
{
protected:
    bool OnInit() { return true; }
};


IMPLEMENT_APP_NO_MAIN(wxDLLApp)

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    wxApp::SetInstance(new wxDLLApp());
    wxEntry(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
    return true;
}


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        ThreadId = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        wxEntryCleanup();
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Cases happening:

1. When I run the Python app using VS Code, I get `wxSocketBase::IsInitialized` error.
2. If I add `wxInitialize()` right before `auto frmPlot` then the error disappears but the frame shows and disappears rather fast. After a few runs then I get the `wxModule::DoCleanupModules` error.
3. Adding `wxUninitialize` right before the function returns seems to clear the error but after a few runs still getting the error at #2.

How can I start a wxFrame (for my application I need to start many) from the *c_plot* function and keep it there until it is closed by the user.

I am using wxWidgets 3.2.2 on Win11.

---

**EDIT 1:**

It looks like the following **partially** works when called from *c_plot* function:

```
wxApp* app = new wxApp();       
auto Init = new wxInitializer();

auto frmPlot = std::make_unique<CFrmSinglePlot>(nullptr);
frmPlot->Bind(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, [&](wxCloseEvent& event)
    {
        delete Init;
        event.Skip();
    });

frmPlot->Show(true);

if(!app->IsMainLoopRunning())
    app->MainLoop();
```

The reason it partially works is that if I would like two show two plot windows or run any other python code such as:

```
plt.c_plot(y1, x1)
print("hello")
```

When I close the frame, the second line is never executed by VS Code.

---

**EDIT 2:**

If `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` is used right before `auto frmPlot` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` right after `app->MainLoop()` and:

```
class PlotThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID

    def run(self):
        plt.c_plot(y, x)

thread1=PlotThread(1)
thread1.start()
print("Hello") #now it is executed
```

then `print("Hello")` statement is executed. However, if one starts another thread along with `thread1`:

```
thread2=PlotThread(2)
thread2.start()
```

then wxWidgets gives the error `wxThread::IsMain`.

Comment: why do you use smat pointer on the main frame?

Comment: @Igor: Although it does not make any difference for this application, you have a good point. It probably messes up with delayed deletion of frames.

Comment: you never know until you test it. ;-)